# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined" when creating pages programmatically in gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to create a blog using gatsbyjs, and would like for my blog pages to be created programmatically instead of explicitly creating them in the /src/pages folder.

I am currently trying to query the data from contentful, which I managed to do successfully according to GraphiQL. I followed the steps presented in the documentation for the most part, but I keep on encountering this error whenever my program steps into the ".forEach" function.

```
exports.createPages=({graphql,actions})=>{
const {createPage}=actions

const blogPost= path.resolve('./src/components/blogComponents/blog-post.js')
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    graphql(`
    {
        allContentfulBlog{
            edges{
              node{
                slug
              }
            }
          }
    }
`).then(results=>{
    // console.log(results)
    if(results.error){
        reject(results.error)
    }
      // create blog post pages
const posts=results.data.allContentfulBlog.edges
console.log(post)

posts.forEach((post,index)=>{
    console.log(`showing slugs: ${posts.node.slug}`)
    const previous= index === posts.length-1?null: post[index+1].node
    const next= index === 0?null: posts[index-1].node



   createPage({
        path:post.node.slug,
        component:blogPost ,
        context:{
            slug:post.node.slug,
            previous,
            next
        } 
    })

    })
}).then(resolve)
})
```

This is the schema of the returned result

```
"data": {
    "allContentfulBlog": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "slug": "web-developer-roadmap"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "slug": "web-fundamentals-1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I expected the "forEach" function to loop through all my blogs and assign the appropriate values the "createPage" function, but instead, it keeps on showing telling me that property of node available in my query is not defined even though I confirmed its presence by logging it to the console as can be seen in the "forEach" function.

Comment: Inside your `forEach` loop, `posts` is a single object and you are accessing it like an array `posts[index+1].node`. Instead it should be `posts.node`. As well,to get the length of an object you can use `Object.keys(posts).length`. `posts.length` will return `undefined`, since it is an object.

Comment: Also, the naming should be appropriate, like you are applying loop for `post`, but instead it should be `posts`(array of posts) and inside loop it should be `post` (single post object) instead of `posts`.

Comment: Thank you randomSoul for your reply, but if you could please check the schema I just edited into the question and confirm whether or not your suggestion stills holds true would be awesome.

Comment: yes, now I see your point about the single object thing you were talking about. Ok so let's say I comment that part out, it still shows me the error even though I traversed it correctly inside the "createPage" function.

Comment: In code `post[index+1]`, are you trying to access next post object based on index?  Then it should be `posts[index+1].node`.

Comment: yes, I am. Oh yeah!! that makes more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code it that you are trying to access object like an array

```
const previous= index === post.length-1?null: post[index+1].node
const next= index === 0?null: post[index-1].node
```

In the above code, `post` is single object. i:e `{ node: {} }` and you are accessing it like an array `post[index+1].node`.

```js
const posts =[
    {
        node: {
            slug: "lorem"
        }
    },
    {
        node: {
            slug: "ipsum"
        }
    }
];


posts.forEach((post, i) => {
    // post is a single object. To access it's node, you need to use post.node
    console.log("current post", post);
    // To access the next post based on index
    if(i<posts.length-1) {
      console.log("Next node", posts[i + 1].node);
    }
});
```

If you want to iterate on the next post based on index, use `posts[index-1].node`. As well make sure to check index, because for last element, `index+1` will throw error.

Comment: yes, it worked! but it's now telling me that I have a graphql problem of an "unknown argument 'slug' ". I am guessing it's arising from the createPage function.

Comment: I don't understand `graphql`, but your error mean that the compiler is not getting definition for `slug`. It seems like error is in this section `graphql({allContentfulBlog{ edges{ node{ slug} } } }` and might be your  `allContentfulBlog` object do not have `slug` property. You can create new thread for this. If the post problem has been resolved, make sure to mark the answer as accepted, so as to indicate that problem has been resolved.

Comment: ok will do that, thank you very much for your help randomsoul.

Comment: hi again @mujeexminiminer, dont forget to mark randomSoul answer as correct, since it resolves your issue with forEach!